# Can Favored Foe from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything target more than one creature at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, targeting, ranger

The new Ranger ability, Favored Foe, says:

> **When you hit a creature** with an attack roll, you can call on your
> mystical bond with nature to mark the target as your favored enemy for
> 1 minute or until you lose your concentration (as if you were
> concentrating on a spell).
>
> **The first time on each of your turns that you hit the favored enemy
> and deal damage to it, including when you mark it**, you can increase
> that damage by 1d4.
>
> **You can use this feature to mark a favored enemy a number of times
> equal to your proficiency bonus,** and you regain all expended uses when
> you finish a long rest.

Since the ability says that you mark the creature when you hit it and that you can use this feature a number of times equal to your proficiency modifier. I am wondering if you could target two creatures in the same turn, since you have Extra Attack at 5th level, to maximize the damage you can deal in a turn.

The scenario I imagine is the following, you attack creature A and mark it, then with your extra attack you attack creature B and mark it. On your next turn, you again attack creature A & B so you can use the **"The first time on each of your turns that you hit the favoured enemy"** clause of Favoured Foe ability to deal the extra damage since both creatures got hit only once on its turn.

Would this work?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

#### No, as marking a foe requires concentration.

Favored Foe states (emphasis mine):

> When you hit a creature with an attack roll, you can call on your mystical bond with nature to mark the target as your favored enemy for 1 minute or until you lose your concentration (*as if you were concentrating on a spell*).

"As if concentrating on a spell" indicates that the usual rules for concentration on spell effects applies here.

The rules for breaking concentration say:

> **Casting another spell that requires concentration**. You lose concentration on a spell if you cast another spell that requires concentration. You can't concentrate on two spells at once.

Marking a second foe would end your concentration on the first mark, since it requires you to concentrate on the second mark.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118116/discussion-between-thomas-markov-and-nick012000).